# Cloud and cloud shadow masking for old LANDSAT and ASTER images in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, landsat, aster, cloud-gis, shadow

I am trying to remove cloud and cloud shadows for Landsat 4-5 ASTER images in GRASS GIS.

I have knowledge that detecting cloud and cloud shadow pixels which is >(255*0.2), but I cannot figure out the appropriate syntax for r.mapcalc?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
r.mapcalc "cloudmask = if(lsatband > 255*0.2, null(), lsatband)"
r.mask cloudmask
```

However, are you sure that the formula is that simple?